# Some categories not displaying products

Tags: product, category, reindex, category-products, price-rules

Today I noticed that my price rules weren't working correctly, so I tried to reindex. I wasn't able to reindex, Magento said. When I looked it up I somewhere read that I should export the table `catalog_catagory_product_index` with **disable foreign key check** checked and then import it back in. When I did that I got an error (I don't remember the exact error).

Now, some of my categories don't display products anymore. I have no idea what the problem might be. https://sportinngerritsen.nl/tennis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently the solution was to truncate the table first before restoring it. Also the products started reappearing when I went to a product, disabled it, saved it, enabled it again and then saved it.